# "bad auth Authentication failed." error while connection to mongodb atlas in python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to mongodb atlas using python using the following code:

```
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:p%40ssword@cluster0-t9lf6.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
mydb = myclient["test"]
mycol = mydb["somecol"]

dblist = myclient.list_database_names() #trial-1

x = mycol.find_one() #trail-2
```

I am getting error for both trail-1 and trail-2 as :

```
OperationFailure: bad auth Authentication failed.
```

Consider my username to be *username* and password to be *p%40ssword* with @ replaced with %40. **I checked my credentials, they are correct**. But still i get this error. What to do ?

Comment: I can successfully connect to my cluster using Python 3.7.3 and Pymongo 3.8.0, using URL-encoded password like yours. Actually, I took your whole code verbatim and try to run it against my cluster and it works. Did you define your users under Security/Database Access/MongoDB Users?

Comment: yes i defined the user and i can see that in Database Access tab also. Did you get results when you ran trail-1 or trail-2 ? Is there any other configuration, i would have missed ? I am using python 3.6.8 with pymongo 3.7.2

Comment: I got the mongo client url as follows: atlas - clusters-connect-connect your application-driver(selected python,version 3.6 or later)-copied the string given and replaced <password> in the string with  'p%40ssword'

Comment: Yes I defined the users in that tab, and also copied the URI from the same place you mentioned. I got results on both trials, no error. I can even `print()` the result out. Could you try creating a new user and see if it still show the same error?

Comment: it worked. I created a new user in Database Access tab. Now i dont get any error. Any reason why it happened before ?

Comment: I have one more doubt. In sql we close a connection once the job is finished. Should we do the same here as well ? If yes how ?

Comment: No idea what happened, but my guess would be the password doesn't match somehow. For your 2nd question, it's best to create a new question instead of discussing it on this question since it's an entirely different topic.